# Do we need to close the response object if an error occurs while calling http.Get(url)?

Tags: go, http, error-handling, defer-keyword

In the following code is it also necessary to close the response body in the error case:

```
res, err := http.Get(url)

if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
}

defer res.Body.Close()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

General concept is that when a function (or method) has multi return values one being an `error`, error should be checked first and only proceed if the error is `nil`. Functions should return zero values for other (non-error) values if there is an `error`. If the function behaves differently, it should be documented. [`http.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get) does not document such deviation.

So it should be handled like this:

```
res, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
    return
}

defer res.Body.Close()
// Read/work with body
```

---

**Notes:**

As JimB confirms too, if a non-`nil` error is returned, even if the response is non-`nil`, we don't have to close it. In case of a redirection error the non-`nil` response may hold context and further information about where following the redirect failed. See details below:

`http.Get()` honors the general concept "most of the time": it returns `nil` response if there is an error:

```
return nil, someError
```

However checking [`client.go`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go), unexported method `Client.doFollowingRedirects()`, currently line #427:

```
if redirectFailed {
    // Special case for Go 1 compatibility: return both the response
    // and an error if the CheckRedirect function failed.
    // See https://golang.org/issue/3795
    return resp, urlErr
}
```

So due to a backward compatibility issue it may return a non-`nil` response and a non-`nil` error at the same time, if redirection fails.

On the other hand trying to call `resp.Body.Close()` if `resp` is `nil` will cause a run-time panic.

So if we want to close response body in this case, it could look like this (can only be closed if `resp` is not `nil`):

```
res, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
}
if res != nil {
    defer res.Body.Close()
    // Read/work with body
}
```

Or:

```
res, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
}
if res == nil {
    return
}

defer res.Body.Close()
// Read/work with body
```

The doc of [`http.Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) guarantees that `Response.Body` will not be `nil` even if there is no response data:

```
// The http Client and Transport guarantee that Body is always
// non-nil, even on responses without a body or responses with
// a zero-length body.
```

**But** if the error is not `nil`, you don't have to close the non-`nil` response body.

Comment: If you ever get a response body that requires closing on an error, that's a bug that needs to be filed. In this case you should have an empty noop closer for the body that is only there to make closing not panic.

Comment: @JimB That's what I thought too. Thanks for confirmation. Will edit the answer.

Comment: I went and double checked the client code, and in the single case where a redirect error returns a Response, the Body has already been closed, and the connection released. Though it doesn't hurt, there should never be a need to `defer resp.Body.Close()` after a client error.

Comment: It's kind of sad that there is that one special case.

Comment: @DrewLeSueur I wouldn't say it's sad: you are not required to close the response in that one special case either (if `err` is non-`nil`).