# Is it required to close the resource body on golang http response?

Tags: go, httpresponse

I just want to ask, on the `http.Client.Do` response, I am just interested on the response status code and the cookie, and I am not gonna read the response body.

If I will not read the body, do I i still required to call `response.body.close()`?

Thanks

Comment: Also related: [Do we need to close the response object if an error occurs while calling http.Get(url)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818472/do-we-need-to-close-the-response-object-if-an-error-occurs-while-calling-http-ge/32819910#32819910)

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, as mentioned I am not going to read the body. Correct me if I am wrong. @icza

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you read it or not, you have to close it. _"The client must close the response body when finished with it"_ Here "when finished with it" means "when you don't need it anymore".

Comment: @icza btw is there any difference  between the ```response.close``` and the ```response.body.close```? it is a little vague for me, on the docs.

Comment: `http.Response` does not have a `Close()` method, only a `Close` field which: _"Close records whether the header directed that the connection be closed after reading Body"_.