# Is resp.Body.Close() required if I don't need response?

Tags: http, go

I'm making request which I don't need response from. Would it cause any problems if I do it like this?

```
client = &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Duration(15 * time.Second),
}
...
...
_, err := client.Do(req)
```

Comment: See [What could happen if I don't close response.Body in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238518/what-could-happen-if-i-dont-close-response-body-in-golang/)

Comment: It is a common question and explained in the documentation to net/http.Client.Do.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from the doc of [`Client.Do()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do)

> If the returned error is nil, the Response will contain a non-nil Body which **the user is expected to close**. If the Body is not both read to EOF and closed, the Client's underlying RoundTripper (typically Transport) may not be able to re-use a persistent TCP connection to the server for a subsequent "keep-alive" request.

So yes, you always have to close it if there is no error. You are also expected to read the body to EOF before closing. Quoting from [`http.Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response):

> ```
> // The default HTTP client's Transport may not
> // reuse HTTP/1.x "keep-alive" TCP connections if the Body is
> // not read to completion and closed.
> ```

If you don't need the body, you may discard it like this:

```
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle error and return
    return
}
defer resp.Close()
io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
```

If there is an error, see related question: [Do we need to close the response object if an error occurs while calling http.Get(url)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818472/do-we-need-to-close-the-response-object-if-an-error-occurs-while-calling-http-ge/32819910#32819910)