# What will happen if defer rows close before error check?

Tags: sql, go

Here is typical use case.

```
rows, err := db.Query(`...`, ...)
if err != nil{
    return
}
defer rows.Close()
...
```

Here is what I want to use.

```
rows, err := db.Query(`...`, ...)
defer rows.Close()
if err != nil{
    return
}
...
```

Will I get a panic?

Comment: "Will I get a panic?" Maybe. Just **don't** do that. It is _dangerous_ and _not_ _useful_.

Comment: Could you please give me some reference to clarify why not to do that?

Comment: Don't do that as `rows` can be nil or otherwise invalid. Just don't do that. That is reference enough.

Comment: Accurate!@Volker

Comment: Will it close rows automatically when an erorr occurs?

Comment: @Chauvet there are no rows to close when an error occurs. When an error occurs the primary return value is `nil`, why would you want to close that? and how would you do it without causing panic?

Comment: Is there any case that the rows is not nil but err exists, in which rows need to be closed?@mkopriva

Comment: @Chauvet It seems like you're hard-set on doing what you've already decided *you want* to do, regardless of the responses you received. You want to call `rows.Close` before error checking but also avoid panics? You can check if `rows` is not `nil` and if it isn't call `rows.Close`, after that block check the error value.  Ultimately it is your code, you do whatever you want however you want...

Answer (score 5):

It may or may not panic. General rule is to always check the returned error first, and if that is `nil`, only then proceed to use other return values.

If you get a non-`nil` error, other return values are "undefined", they may be `nil`, and thus calling their methods may easily result in a runtime panic.

There may be exceptions of course which are usually documented, e.g. [`http.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get) may return an error and a non-`nil` response if following redirection fails, providing details about the error. But this is rare, and should always be documented. [`DB.Query()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) does not document such deviation, so you can't rely on that.

See related: [Do we need to close the response object if an error occurs while calling http.Get(url)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818472/do-we-need-to-close-the-response-object-if-an-error-occurs-while-calling-http-ge/32819910#32819910)

Comment: Could you please give me some links to get those rules which I didn't find in official document?

Comment: @Chauvet This isn't written in stone and you could write code that behaves otherwise (e.g. returns valid results and non-`nil` errors), this is just common sense not to do.